# Guild Join Date shows today date

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a userinfo command for my Discord bot and the line supposed to show me the date when the user joined shows me the date of today.

Here's my code

```js
        let user = interaction.options.getUser("user") || interaction.member.user;
        const target = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.tagetId);

        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(interaction.member.displayHexColor)
        .setDescription(`**Informations ${user.username}**`)
        .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
        .addField(`Username`, `${user.tag}`, true)
        .addField(`ID`, `${user.id}`, true)
        .addField(`Member since`, `${moment.utc(user.joinedAt).format("LL")}`)
        .addField(`Joined Discord on`, moment(user.createdAt).format("LL"))
        .setFooter(`Command used by ${interaction.member.user.username}`, interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: 'true'}));
```

Does somebody know how to do to have the real join date ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the `joinedAt` value from a member, not the corresponding user, e.g. `interaction.member.joinedAt`.

Comment: It says that ``interaction.member`` is not a function

Answer (score -1):

```
    let user = interaction.options.getUser("user") || interaction.member.user;
    const target = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.tagetId);

    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(interaction.member.displayHexColor)
    .setDescription(`**Informations ${user.username}**`)
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .addField(`Username`, `${user.tag}`, true)
    .addField(`ID`, `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField(`Member since`, `${moment.utc(user.joinedAt).format("LL")}`)
    .addField(`Joined Discord on`, moment(user.createdAt).format("LL"))
    .addField(`Server Joined on`, moment.utc(user.joinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY'))
    .setFooter(`Command used by ${interaction.member.user.username}`, interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: 'true'}));
```

Comment: Nop, still not working, but thanks anyways !

Comment: Please, don't post only code as an answer. You should also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

have you put

```
Flags.GUILD_MEMBERS
```

or

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"] });
```

or something like that in your intents in index.js

Comment: Yes, I have put these two things in my index